# How can I get started with Apache, MySQL, and (PHP, Perl, Python) on a Mac?

Tags: php, mysql, perl, apache, macos

What do you recommend for setting the MAMP development stack?

I've seen the quickstart thing at http://www.mamp.info, but I don't really like that approach. I'd rather have a full-fledged Apache that I can install any number of modules into. I remember seeing in the OS X v10.5 (Leopard) Server demo a really slick GUI that allows you to set up all this stuff, add virtual hosts, etc., and I was wondering if anything similar is available for the non-server Leopard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X already comes with Apache, PHP, Perl and Python. Just install MySQL and edit the Apache config file as needed and you should be golden.

Comment: Last time I used the default apache it was not apache2 yet.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Darwin Ports](http://darwinports.com/) or [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) to install everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid heavy [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts) usage. It is a lousy source-based distribution. Avalanche rebuilds, unnecessary default dependencies (xorg for imagemagick). Use binary whenever possible.